# How to test a controller action that expects to receive a JSON array via a POST request?

Tags: json, rest, testing, elixir, phoenix-framework

This should be simple but I just can't figure out what I'm supposed to do. I have a controller action like this:

```
def submit(conn, %{"id" => id, "_json" => results}) do
...
end
```

(The `_json` key is automatically generated by `Plug.Parsers.JSON` on an incoming JSON array)

And I want to test it. However, if I write

```
post(conn, experiment_path(conn, :submit, %{})),
```

or something like

```
post(
  conn,
  experiment_path(conn, :submit, %{
    "id" => "123",
    "_json" => [%{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}, %{"a" => 3, "b" => 4}]
  })
)
```

I get

```
 ** (ArgumentError) maps cannot be converted to_param. A struct was expected, got: %{:_json => %{}, "id" => "123"}
```

The annoying thing is that I'm not sure what type of struct is exactly expected here. I searched around a bit but most of the online resources seem to talk about how to test **sending** JSON responses, not how to receive JSON data.

How should I properly specify the JSON data received by the controller and write the test?

Comment: I’d say you just need to shift a parenthesis a bit :) Instead of passing your params to `experiment_path`, pass it as a third param to `post`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Haha you're right. The third argument to `post` should just be the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @AlekseiMatiushkin in the comments, the incoming JSON should be an argument to `post`, not to `experiment_path`.

This worked:

```
    post(
      conn,
      experiment_path(conn, :submit, "123"),
      %{
        "_json" => [%{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}, %{"a" => 3, "b" => 4}]
      }
    )
```